# Import local Go module in Goland IDE

Tags: go, import, goland, go-modules, vgo

What is proper way to import (use) go module internally?

For example:

creating a new module by: `go mod init example.com/my-project` (example.com or another domain, which doesn't exist)

and using it in the same project:

```
import (
    "example.com/my-project/package"
)
```

This sample was taken from [Let's Go](https://lets-go.alexedwards.net/) book (but extremely simplified)

**The problem:**

I am using Goland, and It doesn't recognize this local module. Goland advice me to use `go get -t example.com/my-project/package` command. But `example.com/...` just a name for a module

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's how that works. What is your question about it?

Comment: What problem did you have? Within the same module, go will find the source as expected.

Comment: @Adrian, I have extended my answer. And that extension describes the problem.

Comment: That looks like an issue with Goland. Have you verified that it works with the go tools themselves?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As @JimB mentioned, the problem related to Goland IDE. I found solution [here](https://github.com/Macilias/goVGOexample).

Enabling Go modules (vgo) integration solves my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer did not help me.

Assume we have two modules in the project (two folders)

```
go mod init example.com/module1
go mod init example.com/module2
```

To able to import module1 from module2 we need to add following code in module2/go.mod:

```
require "example.com/module1" v0.0.0
replace "example.com/module1" => "../my-module"
```